# Help! Validation issue with slideshow?

Tags: validation, slideshow, jwplayer

Hi I'm trying to validate my website but it complains about my slideshow
Is this because its using html? Should I ignore it?

[validator link](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fartygirl.co.uk&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

```
<embed 
src="http://artygirl.co.uk/imagerotator/imagerotator.swf" width="632px" height="308px"
flashvars="file=http://artygirl.co.uk/imagerotator/rotator.xml&transition=blocks&shownavigation=false" 
/>
```

Thanks for your help

Regards

Judi

Answer (score 0):

According to [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/objects.html#h-13.5),  (rather than ) is the tag to use for embedded content. Unfortunately, Internet Explorer supports the  tag, which FF, Chrome, Safari, etc support the  tag.

So how do you create valid content with Flash embedded?

> After a web page has loaded, you can
>   insert the embed tag, effectively
>   circumventing the XHTML problems. As a
>   bonus, you can use JavaScript to
>   determine whether the correct Flash
>   Plugin is available on your visitor's
>   computer. If it isn’t, alternative
>   content can be loaded.

– [LongTail Video's Embedding Flash tutorial](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/13/embedding-flash)

Hopefully this answers your question about how to embed your content in a standards compliant way.

Best,

Zach

Developer, LongTail Video